# Enlarge a single page

Tags: page-breaking, margins

How may I enlarge a single page in LaTeX?

I need this for the summary of a thesis that has to fit on a single page without respect to an eyecandy design.

In order to move the lower border, I was successful using `\enlargethispage{10\baselineskip}`, but I'd like to move the upper and right/left margins as well.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8927916/enlarge-a-single-page-in-latex?noredirect=1) was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: Can there be a pagebreak? Are you using the `geometry` package? If so, you can use `\newgeometry`

Comment: Here's a working answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44439837/2961878

Answer (score 12):

You're enlarging the page with 10 lines? That ought to make the text run below the page. Now we're far away from "eye candy design" :-)

In any case, try adding  a `\vspace*{-10\baseline}` command at the top of the page. That adds negative space and moves the starting point up.

To make the margins smaller (or larger), you can use an environment like this:

```
\newenvironment{wide}{%
  \begin{list}{}{%
      \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{-2cm}%
      \addtolength{\rightmargin}{-2cm}%
      \setlength{\listparindent}{\parindent}%
      \setlength{\itemindent}{\parindent}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\parskip}}%
  \item[]%
}{%
  \end{list}%
}
```

Adjust the -2 cm above to suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks - that's exactly what I was looking for for the upper margin. Now I need something like this to make the right and left margin smaller on that very page.
P.S.: I had to use `\vspace*{-3\baselineskip}` to move the upper border of the text.

Answer (score 7):

You can also use `\enlargethispage{}`. For example, to enlarge the \textheight for the current page by one line, use this command: `\enlargethispage{\baselineskip}`

Comment: the question already lists `\enlargethispage` we wants to increase the other directions too.