# How to adjust last text on last page dynamically?

Tags: page-breaking, widows-orphans

I am writing report and now improving look and feel of the report. I found that last section appears in last of page and its remaininng part on next page which does not look good.

[image]

How can i move sectinon2 and its content to next page dynamically.

Comment: By default, LaTeX will *not*  insert a page break after the first line of a section. Therefore, please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: I think [Enlarge a single page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41595) might what you are looking for. (If this alone fixes the issue for you, please comment here so that we can close this question as a duplicate.)

Comment: No, I need to do it dynamically. My text is variable. It may vary from report to report so i cannot make it fixed.

Comment: @manish I think you should really provide an MWE. `:-)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`needspace` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/needspace) provides a means to conditionally insert content based on the amount of space left on a page. In this instance, you might be after a setup like the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{needspace,lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{needspace,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\section{First section}\lipsum[1-4]
\needspace{6\baselineskip}% <--------- Need 6 lines of text, or insert a page break
\section{Another section}\lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}
```

Comment out the line containing `\needspace` in order to see the difference. You can vary this length to suit your needs, depending on the amount of text that follow `\section{Another section}`, to avoid seeing widowed lines of text.