# Samepage in itemize

Tags: page-breaking, itemize

using itemize as in

```
\begin{itemize}

\item[1] First item

\item[2] Second item   

\end{itemize}
```

Second item gets split between two pages and I don't want that. I tried to use `\begin{samepage}` as in

```
\begin{itemize}

\item[1] First item

\begin{samepage}

\item[2] Second item   

\end{samepage}

\end{itemize}
```

but it still gets split. Do you know how to display an item all in the same page?

Comment: Try to move the samepage outside of itemize

Comment: It is unclear to me whether you want all the items on the same page or they can be on different pages but no item should be split across pages.

Comment: the items can be on different pages but a single item cannot be split across pages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the discussion about [Unbreakable block](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4471/110998). A `\vbox` might do what you want:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
 \item \lipsum
 \item \vbox{\lipsum}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

In this case TeX will start a new page, if the second item does not fit the page, which might result in a lot of white space.

Alternatively, in the final version of the document, you can enlarge single pages by a few lines to make the item still fit on the page. See [Enlarge a single page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41595/110998) for a discussion of this approach. The following example enlarges the page by 8 lines, which is way too much, but a few lines might work.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
 \item \lipsum[1-3]
 \item \enlargethispage{8\baselineskip}%
       \lipsum[4-6]
 \item \lipsum
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: But this vbox doesn't include the bullet, or whatever you h ave which replaces the bullet

Comment: @einpoklum-reinstateMonica Why should it? Which issue do you want to solve that the above code does not address? The code as given above will keep the item on one page, and the bullet appears where the item is.

Comment: Because sometimes the "bullet" can itself be some text which may include a line break.

Comment: @einpoklum-reinstateMonica Having a text (with line breaks) instead of a bullet seems like a creative use of the `itemize` environment for what it is not intended for. Please ask a separate question and give a minimal working example that illustrates what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

Since this is a numbered list, you should use the `enumerate` environment so that numbering is automatic instead of manually numbering each `\item`.  To keep a list `\item` on the same page you could put it inside a `minipage`.

Below, I used the `enumitem` package's `resume` feature to continue the list and place the second item within its own resumed list within a `minipage`.

[image]

### Notes:

- This assumes that the content within the `minipage` fits in *one* page at the most.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*, series=MySeries]
    \item \lipsum[1-2]
\end{enumerate}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}% <-- Kee content from here to end{minipage} on same page.
    \begin{enumerate}[resume*=MySeries]
        \item \lipsum[3-5]   
    \end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `minipage` is not always suitable as, for example, when you have a footnote for one of the items in the list as it inserts this footnote just below `\end{minipage}`, which can be in the middle of the document page.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `\begin{samepage}...\end{samepage}` in a proper way. Such as:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%opening
\title{}
\author{}

\begin{document}
\newbox\one
\newbox\two
\long\def\loremlines#1{%
    \setbox\one=\vbox {%
       Test.\footnote{a footnote}%
      \lipsum\footnote{Another footnote.}%
     }
   \setbox\two=\vsplit\one to #1\baselineskip
   \unvbox\two}
\begin{samepage}
\begin{itemize}
 \item \loremlines{15}
 \item \loremlines{15}
 \item \loremlines{25}
 \end{itemize}
\end{samepage}


\end{document}
```

You will be fine then:

[image]

But without the `samepage` it would not fit in a page:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`\vbox{... }` does the trick I understand you want to do, but you must include `\item` in it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}

\vbox{ \item \lipsum[1-2]
}

\vbox{ \item \lipsum[3-4]
}

\vbox{ \item \lipsum[5-6]
}

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```